# How can I get Vertices with relations and related Vertices in Neo4j 1.9RC1 via Gremlin

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, neo4jclient

Neo4j will support tree pattern in 2.x versions.(We could not use tree function) We are using 1.9RC1.

I need to get Users with Followers and Friends.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...............
}

public class UserModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DetailedInformation { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserModel2> Followers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserModel2> Friends{ get; set; }
}

public class UserModel2
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get tree structured UserModel response.
How can be done via Gremlin..

We were using paths function.

```
g.v(4582).inE.outV.paths{it}
```

But there is data duplication problem for it.
It returns paths not tree.

PS: We are using C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you look how tree() is implemented, it is simply path() aggregated at join points. The join points are vertices at the same depth. Thus, you could create your own tree data structure from the results of path() (--or paths() in older versions of Gremlin). Let me explain how to implement it via example. If you have a set of paths like this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,3,5,6]
[1,2,3,5]
```

Then the tree representation would be:

```
      4
     /
  2-3
 /   \
1     5
 \
  3-5-6
```

A smart use of embedded HashMaps will deliver the functionality you desire. Please look over the Pipes 2.x codebase to see how Tree is implemented and copy (and adjust) to your needs.

Comment: g.v(4582).inE.outV.paths{it} returns matrix that you wrote. But there is data duplication problem. I will check HashMaps. Thanks.

Comment: It seems there is no practical way to achieve this with Neo4J... But with titan everything seems good. @marko what is the release date for titan 0.3.1 ? (I think .1 means production ready)